# Finding if a string contains a string and manipulating attached numbers

Tags: c++, string, find, std, root

Say as part of input, a user inputted nrt:x to tell the program to calculate the nth root of x. If I wanted to send n and x to another method to simplify the nth root, I was thinking I could use std::string::find to look for "rt:". If find returns true, I then need to send n and x to another method, but how could I do that after "rt:" is found? For example, user inputs 7rt:3. Find would return true for "rt:", how could I then send 3 and 7 to another method?

```
if(std::string::find(rt:)) {
    //manipulate numbers before/after rt: from user input
    if(result will be an int) {
        nthRoot(double n, double x);
    }
    If(result will not be an int) {
        nthRootSimplify(double n, double x);
    }
}
void nthRoot(double x, double n){
    double nthRootSol = pow(x, double(1 / n));
}
```

edit: Code I have written as a solution with your guy's help. Any advice would be great. I see myself running into problems if "n" or "z" are longer than 1 int.

```
void findNthRoot(string x) {
if(x.find("rt:") != string::npos) {
    unsigned position = x.find("rt:");
    cout << position << endl;
    double n = position - 1;
    cout << n << endl;
    double z = position + 3;
    cout << z << endl;
    string str1 = x.substr(n, 1);
    string str2 = x.substr(z);
    cout << str1 << endl;
    cout << str2 << endl;

}
}

int main()  {
    findNthRoot("2 - 1+3rt:4");

    return 0;
}
```

output is:
7
6
10
3
4 
with the most important being that "3" and "4" are the values of str1 and str2

Comment: `std::string::find(rt:)` what's this actually? Does it compile?

Comment: This would be checking to see if the string inputted by the user contained an nth root calculation, such as 7rt:3. So since 7rt:3 would be in the string, from there I want to take 7 and 3 from the string to another method. If "rt:" is not in the string, I do not need to worry about an nth root calculatoin. "rt:" is simply custom input instructed by the menu() in this program if the user wants to calculate nth roots

Comment: Since user inputs may vary, and make it hard to decide about validity of such (just using `std::string::find()`), you might be better off using [regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) for parsing the inputs.

Comment: What do you mean by user input may vary? Are you referencing how they may input nth roots?

Comment: _'What do you mean by user input may vary?'_ How do you control the string format that is meant to be entered?

Comment: It is a controlled program done as a group in a school setting. So the fact that we include in the menu(): "If you want to calculate nth roots, use this format - nrt:x" controls the string format. We do not need to worry about varying input

Comment: Besides validation, you also can easily get all your necessary substrings from a parsed regex result. But may be that's all beyond you current conceptions and what you've been asked for to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are assuming that input will always begin with n and end with the number under the radical, you can use `std::string::front()` to access the first element and `std::string::back()` to access the last element.

Answer (score 1):

`find` would **not** return `true`. Such a `find` would be pretty damn useless. The real `std::string::find` returns the *position* of the found string.

Knowing the position, you can now separate your string into the "before" and "after" part using `std::string::substr`.

Comment: So first call find, the fact that it returns the position means that "rt:" is in the string. From there use std::string::substr to take the  numbers before (7 as in 7rt:3) and after (3 as in 7rt:3)? This would work just as well multiple numbers before and after (3432rt:3), correct?

Comment: Read the documentation of `find` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find). Pay attention to `npos`. It should work if you do it correctly, give it a try.

Comment: I gave it try and it turned out pretty well - the only issue I have is if the user inputs something that is larger than one digit as n and x for nrt:x